# Stopping the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Blobs.Listeners.BlobListener' for function <XXX>

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have function app where I have one HttpTrigger and 3 BlobTrigger functions. After I deployed it, http trigger is working fine but for others functions which are blob triggers, it gives following errors

**"Stopping the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Blobs.Listeners.BlobListener' for function "** for one function

**Stopping the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.CompositeListener' for function
"** for another two

I verified with other environments and config values are same/similar so not sure why we are getting this issue in one environment only. I am using consumption mode.

Update: When file is placed in a blob function is not getting triggered.

Comment: Where you are running all those functions, in Azure Portal or Locally?

Comment: In Azure portal @HariKrishna

Answer (score 1):

I created ticket with MS to fix this issue. After analysis I did some code changes as

1. Function was async but returning void so changed to return Task.
2. For the trigger I was using connection string from app settings. But then I changed it to **azureWebJobStorage**(even though bobth were same) in function trigger attribute param

It started working. So posting here in case it is helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

> Stopping the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Blobs.Listeners.BlobListener' for function

I was observed the same message when working on the Azure Functions Queue Trigger:

[image]

This message doesn't mean the error in function. Due to timeout of Function activity, this message will appear in the **`App Insights`** > **`Traces`**.

I have stopped sending the messages in the Queue for some time and has been observed the traces like **`Web Job Host Stopped`** and if you run the function again or any continuous activity is present in the Function, then this message will not appear in the traces.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using elastic Premium and has VNET integrated, the non-http trigers needs Runtime scale monitoring enabled.

You can find Function App-->Configuration--> Function runtime settings and turn on Runtime scale monitoring.

If function app and storage account which holds the metadata of the function Private linked, you will need to add the app settings WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET = 1.

Also, make sure you have private linked for blob, file, table and queue on storage account.