# Azure function stop listener

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function in Python that is triggered by a blob storage. It works fine if, just after deploying, I upload a file to the storage.

However, after that (around 10 minutes), I see the following event in traces:

> Stopped the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Common.Listeners.CompositeListener' for function 'Storage_trigger'

After this, if I upload a new file, it isn't processed unless I redeploy my function.

Any idea how to configure Azure so that the listener is always active, even after a file is processed?

Comment: please share your function code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73879783/stopping-the-listener-microsoft-azure-webjobs-host-blobs-listeners-bloblistener) and git [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1126953/blob-trigger-not-working-or-after-hours)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [MSDOC](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger.md#polling-and-latency) on the Consumption plan, there can be up to a 10-minute delay in processing new blobs if a function app has gone idle.

- I created a created Sample blob trigger with a `Consumption` plan and `app service plan`.
- Tested the trigger with the respective blob after 10 mins I got the results below.
- The `consumption` based plan gave the error below but the Function ran successfully with `App Service Plan`.

**Consumption plan:**

[image]

**App service plan:**

[image]

- For more details refer this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1126953/blob-trigger-not-working-or-after-hours) and  [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73879783/stopping-the-listener-microsoft-azure-webjobs-host-blobs-listeners-bloblistener).